# What causes matlab to read a number from a CSV file as -INF?

Tags: matlab, csv

I am trying to read in CSV files to Matlab. For some reason Matlab is converting some of the numbers to -INF.

I have tried using `readmatrix` and `textscan` functions. `Textscan` forces me to use `str2double` to convert it to a double and it produces the same -INF values as importing the data in with the `readmatrix` function. Is there a better function to read in a CSV file into MATLAB?

Example: -1.79769313486235E308 is being converted to -INF.

**The CSV files are formatted as follows: (with no spaces between the rows)**

```
Header 1, Header 2,           Header 3

190,      -1.47457265853882,  0.0837953791871611

191,      -1.1680064201355,   0.126324314114211

192,      -1.64672422409058,  0.254686301760985

193,      -1.84958028793335,  0.172680441425988
```

Comment: how are your reading the data? (What is the exact code?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within machine precision, `-1.79769313486235E308` is `-Inf`!

From the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html):

> MATLAB constructs the double data type according to IEEE® Standard 754 for double precision. **The range for a negative number of type double is between -1.79769 x 10^308 and -2.22507 x 10^-308**.

So your value here is the most negative value possible for a double in MATLAB. It's likely that Excel uses the same IEEE standard, and is therefore also bottoming out at -Inf just without formatting it accordingly.